# How to implement consumer Thread Safety with Spring-Kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring boot 2.1.7.RELEASE and spring-kafka 2.2.7.RELEASE.And I'm using @KafkaListener annotation to create a consumer and I'm using all default settings for the consumer.

Here is my consumer configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConsumerCommonConfig implements KafkaListenerConfigurer {

      @Bean
      public <K,V> ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(primaryConsumerFactory());
        factory.getContainerProperties().setMissingTopicsFatal(false);
        return factory;
      }

      @Bean
      public DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Object, Object> primaryConsumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(sapphireKafkaConsumerConfig.getConfigs());
      }

}
```

Because of some reasons, I've multiple consumers in the same application as shown below.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "TEST_TOPIC1")
public void consumer1(){

}

@KafkaListener(topics = "TEST_TOPIC2")
public void consumer2(){

}

@KafkaListener(topics = "TEST_TOPIC3")
public void consumer3(){

}
```

With that said, as per the confluent document on 'Consumer Thread Safety'

> You can’t have multiple consumers that belong to the same group in one
>   thread and you can’t have multiple threads safely use the same
>   consumer. One consumer per thread is the rule. To run mul‐ tiple
>   consumers in the same group in one application, you will need to run
>   each in its own thread. It is useful to wrap the con‐ sumer logic in
>   its own object and then use Java’s ExecutorService to start multiple
>   threads each with its own consumer.

Now my question is, should i do anything extra when using the above code using spring-kafka to address this scenario or Doesn't matter because the group would be generated randomly as I didn't specify? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your listeners are configured for different topics. So, their group fully doesn't matter. The group comes to the scene when you have several consumers for the same topic.

Comment: And Spring takes care of the "one consumer per thread" semantics - however, if you use any of the more advanced APIs that expose the raw `Consumer` object (events, listeners etc), you **must** comply with the Kafka directive - do **not** use a reference to that consumer object from a thread other than the one that calls the listener (which, by default, will call any application event listeners where the `Consumer` is exposed in the event).